# Logging basicConfig not creating log file when I run in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run below code in terminal its create a log file

```py
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(filename='ramexample.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

but when I run the same code (with different `filename='ram.log'`) in PyCharm it's not creating any log file. Why?

```py
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(filename='ram.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

What I have to do to create a log file with PyCharm?

Comment: Perhaps PyCharm sets a different working directory, meaning the file ends up in another place. Try providing a full path.

Comment: Your second block of code works perfectly fine and creates a log file for me in PyCharm.

Comment: I provide a full path like below 
logging.basicConfig(filename='home/ra/myapp1.txt', level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('Started')
But No file was created

Comment: @RamnathReddy Have you tried .log instead of .txt with the full file path?
Did you also try an ls/pwd/dir to find out where the terminal is?

Answer (score 145):

I encountered same issue and found none of the answers previously provided here would work. Maybe this issue had been solved long ago to Ramnath Reddy, but I could not find the correct answer anywhere online.

Luckily, I found a solution from a colleague's code by adding the following lines before `logging.basicConfig()`.

```py
# Remove all handlers associated with the root logger object.
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)
```

Try and see if it helps for whomever had the same issue.

**Python 3.8:** A new option, `force`, has been made available to automatically remove the root handlers while calling `basicConfig()`.
For example:

```py
logging.basicConfig(filename='ramexample.log', level=logging.DEBUG, force=True)`
```

See [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) parameters:

> force: If this keyword argument is specified as true, any existing handlers attached to the root logger are removed and closed, before carrying out the configuration as specified by the other arguments.

Comment: This did indeed solve the problem for me. I suspect the issue is a conflict between basicConfig() and a "proper" logging setup elsewhere in the code (I use basicConfig() in tests and a different setup in the regular code). Thanks!

Comment: @zwep , it works because as per the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig , "This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured for it."

Comment: Thanks for insight view. 
For me, adding `force=True` worked & now able to find my updated log file.

Comment: Thanks for this answer which solved my problem with unwritten data and log file, with the option 'force' set to True.

Answer (score 21):

I can't remember where I got this otherwise I would have provided a link. But had the same problem some time ago using in jupyter notebooks and this fixed it:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename='mylog.log', mode='a')
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(fhandler)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 10):

The answer why this error happens is [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file):

> The call to `basicConfig()` should come ***before*** any calls to `debug()`, `info()` etc. Otherwise, those functions will call `basicConfig()` for you with the default options.

If you do so the basicConfig can not create and write a new file, because the default existing stderr WARNING handler already exists.
Here I called `logging.info()` right before `logging.basicConfig()`.

Don't:

```
import logging
logging.info("root") # call to info too early
logging.basicConfig(filename="rec/test.log", level=logging.DEBUG) # no file created
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I had the same issue when my code had top-level imports that created a different logger. So even if you main module begins with `logging.basicConfig` it's quite possible you have logging.info/debug statements elsewhere in you project that are being run first via imports.

Comment: Yes it solved my problem...perhaps a common scenario is that one changed the order of code so some `logging.info()` gets before `logging.basicConfig()`.

Answer (score 7):

Maximas is right. File path is relative to execution environment. However instead of writing down the absolute path you could try the dynamic path resolution approach:

```
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'ram.log')
logging.basicConfig(filename=filename, level=logging.DEBUG)
```

This assumes that `ram.log` resides in the same directory with the one that contains the above code (that's why `__file__` is used for).

Comment: would `filename = ''.join([os.getcwd(),'ram.log'])` be shorter and easier to read?

Comment: @salhin That's relative to the working directory instead of the source code directory, so it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 7):

By using force it get solve.
like `logging.basicConfig(filename="test.log", force=True)`

Comment: This solution is already provided is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49202811/5320906) existing answer.  When answering old questions, please ensure your answer provides a distinct and valuable contribution to the Q&A.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

This does create a log within the pycharm terminal using the Py terminal within it. You need to check the location of where the terminal is (try dir on Windows or pwd on linux/mac). Instead of just putting in ram.log, use the full file path of where you would like the file to appear. 
E.G.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='/Users/Donkey/Test/ram.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: adding the full path after the filename helps!

Answer (score 2):

I used to get this error, but I solved by adding `force=True` in `basicConfig`:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,filename='C:\\Users\\sukal\\PycharmProjects\\Test\\Logs\\Automation.log',format=Log_Format,force=True)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import logging

class LogGen:
    @staticmethod
    def loggen():
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        fhandler = logging.FileHandler(filename='.\\logs\\automation.log', mode='a')
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        fhandler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fhandler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        return logger
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [answer] a question.  The question was asked 5 years ago.