# Write a program to generate a log

Tags: python, logging, arguments, parameter-passing

My Text file

`192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] "PUT /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0" 200 5042 "http://cooper.com/homepage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/5342 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.870.0 Safari/5342"
10.30.24.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] "POST /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0" 200 4939 "http://www.cole-brown.net/category/main/list/privacy/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/5322 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.843.0 Safari/5322"
98.5.45.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:49 +0000] "GET /apps/cart.jsp?appID=8471 HTTP/1.0" 200 4958 "http://knight-chase.com/post.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_7_3; rv:1.9.6.20) Gecko/2013-11-03 17:44:01 Firefox/3.8"
94.5.6.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:48:56 +0000] "GET /list HTTP/1.0" 200 4891 "http://thomas.com/explore/wp-content/homepage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_4; rv:1.9.5.20) Gecko/2013-02-19 05:36:22 Firefox/3.6.15"`

Input from user expected:
 1) Number of lines to generate

2) output to file or console

3) Provide a help when no arguments to the program is given.

4) Ensure that number of lines generated by the program is the number entered by the user of this program. (Think large numbers)

python3 test.py --help   (it should display help options)

python3 test.py -N 20  -type console  (it should print the log in console)

python3 test.py -N 10  -type log -name abc.log  (it should print the log in a file)

My Psedo Code

```
 import sys
 from itertools import islice

 args = sys.argv
 print (args)
 #['file.py', 'datafile', '-N', '10']
 if args[1] == '-h':
     print ("-N for printing the number of lines: python file.py datafile -N 10")
 if args[2] == '-N':
     datafile = args[1]
     number = int(args[3])
     with open(datafile) as myfile:
         head = list(islice(myfile, number))
         head = [item.strip() for item in head]
         print (head)
         print ('\n'.join(head))
```

Is there any better way of approach than this like `argument passing`

Comment: please refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49580313/create-a-log-file

Comment: you can prepare an `INI` or `YAML` files, and control program with them.

Comment: Of course, the arguments must somehow come from the console to the program. So an argument passing is inevitable. However, there are libraries that can take care of the further processing of these user inputs. I instantly think of three tools that work well with *parsing* arguments: [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), [docopt](http://docopt.org/) and [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com).

Answer (score 3):

For command line arguments use the Python standard library [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("type")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.type == "console":
    print("log to console here")
elif args.type == "log":
    # log to file here
    pass
```

Answer (score 3):

This program will **by default print lines in console**, if the **output_file** is not specified.

```
def parsing_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter,
                                     description="""Write what your tool is doing here""")
    parser.add_argument("-n",
                        "--number_of_lines",
                        type=int,
                        help="Number of line to be generated",
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-o",
                        "--output_file",
                        default=None,
                        help="output file used for saving logs")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    output_to_console = args.output_file is None 

    return {"number_of_lines": args.number_of_lines,
            "output_file": args.output_file
            "output_to_console":args.output_to_console}

def line_generator_function(number_of_lines,output_file,output_to_console):
    lines = ... # custom logic here # assuming that lines is a list of strings 
    if output_to_console is True:
        print(*lines, sep="\n")
    else:
        with open(output_file, "wt") as out:
            print(*lines, sep="\n", file=out)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    arguments = parsing_arguments()
    line_generator_function(**arguments)
```

The **--help is automatically provided** by argparse. It will print both main description and help provided to argument description. As well as it is called **without any arguments.**

And if you need **dekstop GUI** you can check this tool. [Gooey](https://github.com/chriskiehl/Gooey)