# How to toggle Jupyter Notebook display logging

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to apply logging to Jupyter Notebook's `display(df)` functionality. How do I edit the last line of my code so that the dataframe is only displayed if logging INFO is active? Currently it's shown whether the logging is active or inactive.

```
import pandas as pd

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

filename = 'test.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, encoding='utf-8')

logging.info(display(df))
```

Comment: `display(df)` is evaluated (and rendered to the notebook) before it is sent to `logging.info()` - it is not lazy evaluated, so this approach will not work. Equivalent to `logging.info(print(df))` - `print(df)` will always output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently it's shown whether the logging is active or inactive.

I guess you are saying that when you change the argument `level` of `logging.basicConfig`, the result doesn't change along with it. That happens to me, too. After checking [logging - Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) and [Logging basicConfig not creating log file when i run in pycharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861524/logging-basicconfig-not-creating-log-file-when-i-run-in-pycharm), I am able to come out a solution:

```
for handler in logging.root.handlers[:]:
    logging.root.removeHandler(handler)

logging.basicConfig(format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.debug("\n"+str(df))
logger.info("\n"+str(df))
logger.warning("\n"+str(df))
logger.error("\n"+str(df))
logger.critical("\n"+str(df))
```

You can play with `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` to see if it works.

And since `display(df)` would be called anyway just like @AChampion says, I use `"\n"+str(df)` to replace `display(df)`.

Output:

```
 2019-01-18 14:20:47,710 - DEBUG - 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
 2019-01-18 14:20:47,715 - INFO - 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
 2019-01-18 14:20:47,720 - WARNING - 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
 2019-01-18 14:20:47,724 - ERROR - 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
 2019-01-18 14:20:47,728 - CRITICAL - 
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9
```

Comment: Thanks. I can get your above code to work, however I'm wanting to use display(df) as it outputs a formatted table.

Comment: @Deskjokey I've added the result above, and I think it looks just like the result of `display(df)`.

Comment: Gah I could not figure out what was happening with duplicate log records but it appears that in IPython a streamhandler is added to the root logger? thank you for pointing me to this

Answer (score 0):

The currently accepted answer shows the `str` representation of the dataframe, whereas I believe the OP was interested in logging the IPython html repr. This can be achieved with a custom `Handler`:

```
import logging

class DisplayHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.addFilter(lambda record: hasattr(record.msg, '_repr_html_'))
    
    def emit(self, record):
        display(record.msg)

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(DisplayHandler())
```

Now display depends on log level:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]})

logger.info(df)
```

shows nothing, but for a warning, the dataframe is displayed:

```
logger.warning(df)
```

[image]

Now both the default and the custom handlers are handling the dataframe; to filter it from the default handler we can do

```
logger.handlers[0].addFilter(lambda record: not hasattr(record.msg, '_repr_html_'))
```

Now we have

```
logger.warning(df)
```

[image]

The same handler works for any object that has a html repr, for example, matplotlib figures:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 2))
x = np.arange(0., 10., 0.2)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))

logger.warning(fig)
```

[image]