# Can't output any file in Python. Logger, Pandas, Open()

Tags: python, logging, output, logfile, python-logging

I wanted to run this piece of code to see if anything outputs. I ran pieces of code like this in my work windows VM and it works perfectly. I switch over to my local Windows computer and I can't understand for the life of me why this can't output anything if I'm in a folder on my desktop.

I'm using Python 3.9.6. I thought it was a root logging problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861524/logging-basicconfig-not-creating-log-file-when-i-run-in-pycharm) because that is what I was testing at first. But then realized I can't output anything. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2. Then tested on sublime and nothing worked. I am getting no errors. My working directory is also correctly set to the directory I'm in. Giving the full path does not work either.

I am using Windows 10.

```
import logging
import pandas as pd


# Cant create logger
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')

# Cant Create CSV
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Raphael', 'Donatello'],
                   'mask': ['red', 'purple'],
                   'weapon': ['sai', 'bo staff']})
df.to_csv("csv_file.csv",index=False)


# Can't output empty text file.
with open('sample.csv', 'w') as creating_new_csv_file: 
   pass
```

Comment: If the code did not raise an exception, then the files _were_ created.  They will be created in the current directory.  Do you know what directory it is using?  You can use `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to show the current directory.

Comment: Yes I'm running this file from a directory on my desktop. os.getcwd() returned the directory the code is running in.

Comment: Running the code line by line in the terminal after entering the python command works.

Comment: do you get an error?  what does "can't" mean in this context?

Comment: No there are no errors and can't means it does not show up in the cwd which is what is expected

Comment: Add some `print()` statements to the code and try running it again.  Do the messages show up in the output window?

Comment: Yes the os.cwd() printed. I just added hellos before and after each command, they all showed up.

Comment: Hmm.  Very strange.  Add this code and show the output: `import os; print(os.listdir())`

Comment: Oh man it is all there! I just can't see it physically in my folder. They are not hidden either! Wow what a trip. I just searched my file explorer and it found one of the files. How the hell did the output end up in:
C:\VTRoot\HarddiskVolume3\Users\Vinny C\Desktop\running_JJ_locally instead of
C:\Users\Vinny C\Desktop\running_JJ_locally

After looking up the VTRoot folder it seems it has to do with me downloading COMODO.

Comment: Got it! I needed to "Open the comodo, click on the settings, then click on the Containment, then click on the Auto-containment, then at the top, uncheck the enable auto-containment."

Thank you John Gordon the print(os.listdir()) helped.